# Column Bar chart filtered by Top N Values in Power BI Paginated Report

Tags: filtering, greatest-n-per-group, powerbi-paginated-reports

Let's supposed I have this dataset:

[image]

If I order it by Value (Z->A), I get this:

[image]

If I create a column chart based on the Top 6 Values, I'm getting the right result:

[image]

But if I try to do the same with the Area, I'm getting all the Values in the chart:

[image]

This is the configuration for the category group:

[image]

What do I need to change in order to reach the expected result, just the 6 first values represented in the column chart by area.